# How can I edit a PDF document using Unix commands and no GUI?

Tags: unix, pdf, ghostscript

I want to be able to search some text and replace or remove it from the PDF document.

I tried `pdf2ps`. The resulting `.ps` document did not respond to `grep` or `sed` commands.

Are there any tools that can simply allow me to `grep` or `sed` or use a similar function?

- `xpdf` did not allow me run its functions under Unix.
- `pdfedit` needs a GUI, which I want to avoid using.

Does `ghostscript` allow PDF editing? If yes, what is the function to use?

Comment: [XY](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2449/5763): What do you really want to do?

Comment: Suppose my PDF document has a text "sireesha" in several places, I want to be able to search and remove the string "sireesha" from the document or replace it with some empty spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler_%28software%29):

> Poppler comes with a text-rendering back-end as well, which can be invoked from the command line utility pdftotext. It is useful for searching for strings in PDFs from the command line, using the utility grep, for instance.

This will not solve your whole problem, as you want to edit as well, but Poppler might be a lib to build a tool on, if there should be no such tool available.
It seems to have functionality to handle the PDF format, which is not trivial:

> The PDF combines three technologies:
>
> - A subset of the PostScript page description programming language, for generating the layout and graphics.
> - A font-embedding/replacement system to allow fonts to travel with the documents.
> - A structured storage system to bundle these elements and any associated content into a single file, with data compression where appropriate.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format)

Comment: Thank you. That worked. How do I convert the txt back to PDF? Or rather, how should a txt be converted back to pdf?

Comment: That is the hard part. I understand that you want to modify a PDF doc, thus keeping its layout more or less. I don't know a text based tool that can do this. Maybe someone else does. If your page layout is not that important / simple, you might generate the modified pdf pages yourself (e.g. using pdfLaTeX) and use some pdf tool to replace the page within the original PDF file by the newly generated ones.

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. I will try something out!

Comment: pdftk is very nice for rearranging PDF files. If pdfLaTeX is too much, go for something simpler, there seems to be a text2pdf tool but I have not used it yet.